# Xaml Parsing Failed when subclassing ListView/GridView/ListBox

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I am subclassing `ListView` in a Windows Universal App Project. I create a new UserControl in Visual Studio 2015 RC and then change the UserControl type to ListView in both XAML and codebehind.

When I insert the control and run the application I get a 'Xaml Parsing Failed' exception without any further information.

Upon researching I came across the issue where the project name contains a dot, but my project name does not contain such characters.

Any Idea how to research this further?

EDIT: I also tried subclassing ListView, GridView, ListBox and Itemscontrol. Itemscontrol does not generate the error but all others do.

EDIT 2:

1. Created a new Universal App Project in VS2015 RC
2. Add -> UserControl
3. Changed Base Class into:

   public sealed partial class ListViewEx : ListView
   {
       public ListViewEx()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
4. Changed XAML UserControl tag into ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8b5ff740-9f66-4f68-b168-aa8faac02496/uwpxamlxaml-parsing-failed-when-subclassing-listboxlistviewgridview): use themed control (custom control) for this case.

However, this approach works in WPF, it surprises me.